# rounded rectangle dashed lines

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am writing some additional drawfunction for the canvascontext. The code below should alow the user to draw rounded rectangles with dashed lines or normal lines. This is almost fully working code, but at the end of the drawing, there is an additional line drawn at a rounded corner (I included a picture of that problem). Note that this problem only occurs when I draw the rectangle dashed, the other version works perfect.

```
if (window.CanvasRenderingContext2D && CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.lineTo){
        CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.dashedLine = function(pt1, pt2, dashLen) {
                if (dashLen == undefined) dashLen = 6;

                var dX = pt2.x - pt1.x;
                var dY = pt2.y - pt1.y;
                var dashes = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY) / dashLen);
                var dashX = dX / dashes;
                var dashY = dY / dashes;

                var q = 0;
                while (q++ < dashes) {
                 pt1.x += dashX;
                 pt1.y += dashY;
                 this[q % 2 == 0 ? 'moveTo' : 'lineTo'](pt1.x, pt1.y);
                }
                this[q % 2 == 0 ? 'moveTo' : 'lineTo'](pt2.x, pt2.y);
            };
        CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundRectangle = function(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, dashed, dashLen) {
              function line(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, dashed) {
                if (dashed) ctx.dashedLine({x:x1, y:y1}, {x:x2, y:y2});
                else {
                    ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);}
              }
              var radius = 8;
              this.beginPath();
              line(this, pt1.x + radius, pt1.y, pt2.x - radius, pt2.y, dashed);
              this.quadraticCurveTo(pt2.x, pt2.y, pt2.x, pt2.y + radius);
              line(this, pt2.x, pt2.y + radius, pt3.x, pt3.y - radius, dashed);
              this.quadraticCurveTo(pt3.x, pt3.y, pt3.x - radius, pt3.y);
              line(this, pt3.x - radius, pt3.y, pt4.x + radius, pt4.y, dashed);
              this.quadraticCurveTo(pt4.x, pt4.y, pt4.x, pt4.y - radius);
              line(this, pt4.x, pt4.y - radius, pt1.x, pt1.y + radius, dashed);
              this.quadraticCurveTo(pt1.x, pt1.y, pt1.x + radius, pt1.y);

              this.closePath();
              this.stroke();
              this.fill();
        }
```

}

[image]

Does anybody know what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The `this.closePath();` line add that last straight line. Just remove it.

Also, to get a better result, remove the `this.beginPath();` line and add the following one instead:

```
this.moveTo(pt1.x + radius, pt1.y);
```

Check the modified code: http://jsfiddle.net/W8b3e/

Comment: Thank you for solving that issue, but I wanted to add the fill option so that the background can be coloured. When I do this, only the quadratic curve areas are coloured, so I need that path. I changed the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/W8b3e/2/